# Gradient is not working in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Firefox 26.0 and IE 8 are giving me issues. Works fine in chrome. Been stuck for a long time now, anyone can help me out?

.sectionBoxTitle {

```
height: 40px;
margin: 0px 0 60px 0;
padding: 0;
color: white;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, ##0b4bbb, #007fe4);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0b4bbb), to(#007fe4))
```

}

Comment: You can use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate gradients more easily. The syntax you're using is by far not complete.

Comment: Why would you expect it to work in IE when you've only specified Firefox and Chrome/Safari vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cross-browser solution that should help you out. I think it covers most scenarios:

```
.sectionBoxTitle {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;

    /* For Browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-color: #0b4bbb;
    /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#0b4bbb),to(#007fe4));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#0b4bbb,#007fe4);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#0b4bbb,#007fe4);
    /* For IE 6,7,8,9 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0b4bbb',endColorstr='#007fe4');
    /* IE 10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#0b4bbb,#007fe4);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0b4bbb,#007fe4);
    /* CSS 3 Support */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#0b4bbb 0,#007fe4 100%);  
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/4LGes/)**

Documentation: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

Comment: Your class selector is missing a `.` prefix.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Good call. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need is the following:

```css
.sectionBoxTitle {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px 0 60px 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    background: #0B4BBB; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0B4BBB 0%, #007FE4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0B4BBB), color-stop(100%, #007FE4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0B4BBB 0%,#007FE4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0B4BBB 0%,#007FE4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0B4BBB 0%,#007FE4 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0B4BBB 0%,#007FE4 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0b4bbb', endColorstr='#007fe4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/92B8K/2/).

You'll need all these browser-specific prefixes for it to work in every browser. Just specifying `-moz-` and the old syntax for `-webkit-` probably used to cover all browsers that would support gradients back in 2010, but nowadays there are more browsers that support it, so more browsers to add prefixes for.

*This code was taken directly from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. I only changed the color format from `rgba()` to `#HEX`.*